# Keeping a web app running on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, npm

I have an Angular2/NodeJS app running on a Linode Ubuntu server. I start the app using npm start and the app will stay running until the Terminal window on my mac is closed on times out. What should I be doing to keep the app/site running?

Comment: `nohup` and `&` at the end or better yet use a service for keeping the app running, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service

Comment: In addition, you can use web server applications such as Apache and/or Tomcat.

Comment: @ryekayo Thanks, I'm looking at using & or forever command. I have just found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small utility called `screen` which lets you keep a process running after you disconnect.

You can look at the man page for this tool, just look it up by running this command: `man screen`.

Take a look at this [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen) for some examples and how to use it.